# symfony database access configuration problem

Tags: mysql, database, version-control, symfony1

I just joined a web dev project that uses Symfony 1.4 on CentOS 5.4 with MySQL. The server is down. My first task in the project is to get it back up. I don't know a lot about Symfony.

The Apache server log says
`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

From all I can tell, the database access configuration is stored in
`/var/www/html/<project name>/config/databases.yml`
and for some reason, there's also some config in
`/var/www/html/<project name>/config/propel.ini`

There was no password for user root in either of the files, so I thought adding it and restarting Apache would finx the issue. It does not, the error message stays the same. I might be looking at the wrong config files, but I can't find any other.

Any wild guesses how to fix this ?

Cheers,

ssc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I know now what I did wrong: The password indeed has to be added to databases.yml, but whenever the configuration is changed, the symfony cache needs to be cleared by executing

```
./symfony cc
```

in the `/var/www/html/<project name>/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the database config file is stored at /WEB/project/config/databases.yml

You can also try to run the configure:database command from the symfony command line tool.

```
php symfony configure:database "mysql:host=DBHOST;dbname=DBNAME" USER PASS
```

A getting started guide, and much more can be found at:  http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/